# Setting the default value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between setting the default value the following ways and which one is correct?

```
1) var1 = var1 || 'default_value'
2) var1 = typeof(var1) !== 'undefined' ? var1 : 'default_value'
3) var1 = var1 !== 'undefined' ? var1 : 'default_value'
4) var1 = var1 != 'undefined' ? var1 : 'default_value'
```

Comment: They all do very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These all do very different things:

1. `var1 = var1 || 'default_value'`

   `var1` will equal `'default_value'` if `var1` is [falsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) (`NaN`, `false`, `0`, `''`, `undefined`). This means if `var1` is any of those values (perhaps most notably `false`, `0`, or `''`), `var1` will equal `default_value`.
2. `var1 = typeof(var1) !== 'undefined' ? var1 : 'default_value'`

   `var1` will equal `'default_value'` if `var1`'s type is strictly equal to `'undefined'`.
3. `var1 = var1 !== 'undefined' ? var1 : 'default_value'`

   `var1` will equal `'default_value'` only if `var1` is not strictly equal to the string `'undefined'`.
4. `var1 = var1 != 'undefined' ? var1 : 'default_value'`

   `var1` will equal `'default_value'` only if `var1` is not equal to the string `'undefined'`.

The last two are probably erroneous. You rarely want to check to see if the value of a variable is the string `'undefined'`. You probably meant to check against `undefined` directly.

To fully understand each of these, you should read about the differences between the strict equality (`===`) operator and the equality operator (`==`). [MDN's comparison operators article is quite good at explaining this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Answer (score 1):

The second one is the *most* correct of the four.  It will work as you intend (if variable is not set, use default value).

1. This will also use default value if `var1` is falsey (`0`, `false`, `null`, `''`, as well as `undefined`)
2. This will use the default value if `var1` is not equivalent to the string `'undefined'`
3. This will use the default value if `var1` is not equal to the string `'undefined'`.

Answer (score 1):

The first and second works, but for different conditions.

The third and fourth compare the value to the string `"undefined"` which doesn't at all determine if it's an undefined value.

The first method uses the default if the current value evaluates to false. That works for most values, but if you for example used it with `true` as default for a boolean value, it would not be possible to set it to `false` and have that survive the test:

```
var var1 = false;

var1 = var1 || true;
```

Now it's `true` eventhough it already had a value. You will have the same problem with some other specific values, like `0` or `""`.

The second one is the one that works most consistently with different data types. The first one is however often used because it's shorter.